# Alternative for String type in smart contract and Solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, gas, gas-price, string

Regarding the fact using String in contract is expensive, is there any alternative type in Solidity ?

The input value (Payload) I want to set is as follows :

```
{"SQN":4,"Node_ID":"00deadface0102030405060708090a0b","Energy":"5.00","Power":"1.80","Sign":"54c5645616a8567d605bd990df0456913420fb630860316cf29bf57e19ef3102933ac948e672a4e3dfa8b7e20cc9eb44520aa8d8dc69143a5bc718a17a1d3f2dfc0084f172dbda6dd38e411e75100136d95d46e3d563c3a0aed062c40c6d17a5038ef0ad681622245bd2332008b1edca693b3418df1f5f86f09a6585d4af7da0d2ab44f5ce1c7ec8eed51696697b2674a881868be7163eda7c6562d02bdf069fcd66d483e8b22c5c976d27c04ffe38e62800eec17f1786b2f2161fcf44b91ba85a4486edb48a5c5a2f58dc1fa3969917eadabd7af753947de4a7f03034de09adb3b1cacb77e21444eee2d90944037606f84d0aa99f4794e8df8a2d0fbfff55c7"}
```

Comment: use events instead storing as string or bytes

Comment: @BadrBellaj Bellaj Thank you. Would you explain me a bit more how to declare such this event ? ex. event MyEvent(uint256 SQN, ....); I'm wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use events to store your data as it's a cheaper storage alternative.

```
event payload(uint256 indexed SQN, ....);
```

you can use an indexed variable to use it as an index to retrieve your input.
in the front-end you can use get to retrieve the events or watch to catch fired ones.

Comment: Thank you, but how about for  "Sign" field since it contains both digit and letter ? I cannot define it as uint256 Sign, Isn't it ?

Comment: no it's a string, the difference here is you're using a string in an event not as a state

Comment: but as I mentioned in my question i want to avoid using string since it's expensive in contract.

Comment: it's expensive if used as a variable not as a parameter for event. read this post to know more https://media.consensys.net/technical-introduction-to-events-and-logs-in-ethereum-a074d65dd61e otherwise you can store data off-chain in ipfs or other systems