# What is a cheap way to store mnemonic generator list of 1024 words in smart contract?

Tags: contract-development, storage, string

What is the cheapest way to store a list of 1024 words for a mnemonic generator, and why?

These ideas had a gas cost of 165720 GAS for a string array, and 42300 GAS for storing all the words in a byte array, 6 byte per word.

```
contract mnemonicgenerator {

bytes public listBytes;

string[] public listString;

function storeString() {
    listString.push("about");
    listString.push("above");
    listString.push("abroad");
    listString.push("accept");
    listString.push("access");
}

function storeBytes() {
    bytes memory toBytes = new bytes(6*5);
    assembly {
      mstore(add(toBytes, 32), "about")
      mstore(add(toBytes, 38), "above")
      mstore(add(toBytes, 44), "abroad")
      mstore(add(toBytes, 50), "accept")
      mstore(add(toBytes, 56), "access")
    }
    listBytes = toBytes;
}
}
```

and a bytes6 array costs 104258 GAS

```
bytes6[] public listBytes6;

function storeBytes() {
      listBytes6.push("about");
      listBytes6.push("above");
      listBytes6.push("abroad");
      listBytes6.push("accept");
      listBytes6.push("access");
}
```

Comment: check out this answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/47254/alternative-for-string-type-in-smart-contract-and-solidity/47261#47261

Comment: the idea is that the mnemonic generator should be readable on-state, by other contracts

Comment: A `Trie` is an efficent way of storing a dictionary of words: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi feel free to write an answer

Comment: What is the use of the word list? Do you want to validate a mnemonic? Since the word list does not change, I'd store them as constant in the contract if that is possible, the compiler can optimize them to minimize costs.